# Copy and Paste greyed out in sharepoint Designer 2010 for site owner

Tags: sharepoint-designer

A user wants to copy and paste pages in Sharepoint designer. As admin, I can do it but she can not. Her paste option is greyed out.  I confirmed that the user has "full control" access at the site level.

What's wrong?

Comment: The issue seems to be with Sharepoint Designer on Windows XP. Even when logged in with my account, which works on my computer (windows server 2008), she can not copy and paste so it is not a permission issue.  
  
I tried clearing the Sharepoint Designer Cache by deleting the files found here:  
  
- %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache  
and  
- %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application   Data\Microsoft\WebsiteCache  

Nothing helped, next step is to unistall, reinstall SPD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by reinstalling Sharepoint Designer